# Есть ли какие то замечания к алгоритму для заполнения переменной класса string n случайными символами

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

Пожалуйста подскажите можно ли реализовать это лучше и компактнее.
   Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
    int main()
    {
            setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

        std::string str;
            int lenght;
            std::cout << "Введите длину строки: ";
            std::cin >> lenght;

        char symbols_library [] {"!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"};
        char temp[lenght + 1];
        temp[lenght] = '\0';
        srand(time(NULL));
            for(int i = 0;i < lenght;i++)
            {
                temp[i] = symbols_library[rand() % 94];
            }

            str.assign(temp);
            std::cout <<  str;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Если вам гарантировано надо, чтобы в результате `str` не было повторов, то сначала скопируйте (можно сразу при инициализации) туда `symbols_library`, а потом перемешайте (меняя `str[i]` с `str[random() % length]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поудаляйте лишнее и будет сильно короче

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
    int main()
    {
        int lenght;
        std::cout << "Введите длину строки: ";
        std::cin >> lenght;

        const char symbols_library [] {"!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"};
        srand(time(NULL));
        std::string str(lenght, ' ');
        for(int i = 0;i < lenght;i++)
        {
            str[i] = symbols_library[rand() % sizeof(symbols_library)];
        }
        std::cout <<  str;
        return 0;
    }
```

вот такая штука `char temp[lenght + 1];` - это VLA, поддерживается gcc/clang, но как расширение (то есть, для плюсового кода крайне не рекомендована).

И напоследок. Если написано "алгоритм", то может код заполнения вынести в отдельную функцию?

А что бы вообще было хорошо, лучше `sizeof(symbols_library)` поменять немного. Вместо

```
const char symbols_library [] {"!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"};
```

написать

```
std::string symbols_library {"!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"};
```

И вместо

```
sizeof(symbols_library)
```

написать

```
symbols_library.length()
```

Comment: Кажется VLA в C++ gcc преобразует во что то типа `new type[number];` , или ошибаюсь? То есть это только синтаксис описания, результат в ассемблере будет иным.

Comment: нет, там обычно используется выделение памяти на стеке.

Comment: Думаю, нужно использовать `(sizeof(symbols_library) - 1)`, иначе есть шанс взять нулевой байт с конца строки.

Comment: а результат % обычно не бывает больше делителя.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6f1cb2db4be032e

Comment: сделаем код более плюсовее и уберем проблему.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string symbols_library{"!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"
       "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
       "0123456789"},     str; 
std::generate_n(back_inserter(str), length,
                [&](){ return  symbols_library[rand() % 94];});
cout << str;
```